# wpdb prepare without placeholder

Tags: sql

Recently, I found out why there are a lot of `PHP Notice` on my debug.log. It is because of `wpdb:prepare` needing placeholders. Documentation says that I need to do:

```
$wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `column` = %s AND `field` = %d OR `other_field` LIKE %s", array( 'foo', 1337, '%bar' ) ) );
```

But for me I use:

```
$wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `column` = " . $foo . " AND `field` = " . $intvalue . " OR `other_field` LIKE " . $bar ) );
```

Since I find it easier to read. If I do the 2nd option, can I skip `$wpdb->prepare` if I use the 2nd option? Or should I change my query to the 1st option since this is what is in the documents.

Comment: Please don't ever, EVER! use the second option, passing raw data to a sql query is just asking for trouble, always use prepare, the intended way, check the official documentation on how to work with it

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**:
You should use the way described in the documentation, sanitize anything that goes in an SQL query, and always use prepared statements.

**Slightly longer answer**:
The main use of `$wpdb->prepare()` is to prevent against SQL injection attacks.
Here, we don't know where `'foo'`, `1337` and `'%bar'` come from. And that's somewhat the deciding factor.

From a security perspective:

- If it doesn't come *in any way* (even indirect) from user input, it's ok not to use prepared statements
- If it comes from user input, even indirectly, the prepared statement is required
- Most importantly, no one can predict the future: these variables' value may not, directly or indirectly, come in any way from user input, but an update down the line might change that.

Comment: And by "user", I mean it also includes admins

Comment: I see. Thank you for the input. I will try to change the way how my code is written. For now, I will keep it as is since it is currently working as intended.